# How to handle back arrow click?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am developing an Android app about music. In this app, I have two fragments: PopFragment e GenresFragment.
In the XML file of PopFragment called fragment_pop.xml, I have toolbar with a back arrow that goes back to GenresFragment.
My toolbar code is this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >
<include
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/arrowPop"
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    />
```

In the Java file of PopFragment called PopActivity, I have some code but it's not working.
I have this code:

```
public class PopActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


public PopActivity() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pop);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    ImageButton backBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.arrowPop);
}

@Override
public void onClick (View view) {

    Intent i = new Intent();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.arrowPop:
            break;
    }
}
```

Can you help me please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't need to add your own arrow icon, the Toolbar should be able to handle it for you.

```
if(shouldShowArrow()) {
   drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, GravityCompat.START);
   drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
   MyActivity.this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
} else { // hamburglar icon
   drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, GravityCompat.START);
   MyActivity.this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
   drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
}
drawerToggle.syncState();
```

And then you can define what happens when you click the arrow

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MyActivity.this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            MyActivity.this.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            MyActivity.this.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

    drawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // what to do when you click the arrow
        }
    });
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onPostCreate(bundle);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
protected void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code as a quick fix, which mimics the back button being pressed.

```
switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.arrowPop:
        onBackPressed();
        break;
}
```

Using this code, you shouldn't have to define the back button in the toolbar yourself, Android will handle it.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Then when you click the back button, Android will call `onBackPressed()` for you.